# Livewire3 - prevent wire:navigate scroll to top default behavior

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Is there any way to prevent livewire from scrolling to top of the page after navigation is complete?
I want livewire to maintain current window scroll position.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after browsing livewire github, I found the lines responsible for scrolling:
https://github.com/livewire/livewire/blob/main/js/plugins/navigate/scroll.js

```
export function restoreScrollPositionOrScrollToTop() {
    let scroll = el => {
        if (! el.hasAttribute('data-scroll-x')) {
            window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'instant' })
            ...
```

So we can register following listener:

```
document.addEventListener("livewire:navigated", () => {
    // Add data-scroll-x to body:
    document.body.setAttribute("data-scroll-x", window.scrollX);
})
```

Now Livewire kinda "maintains" scroll position.
It would be much better if this was configurable because depending on how much delay is before livewire:navigated event and actual scrolling the user may encount interface jumps.

Comment: the code you provided helped me to set it to smooth scrolling since the default behavior just jumped to the top.

`document.addEventListener('livewire:navigated', () => {
        document.body.setAttribute("data-scroll-x", window.scrollX);
        window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: "smooth"});
})`